# Eclipse build succeeding but command line giving 'code too large' error

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

I'm facing a very silly problem.

If I build my project using the Eclipse UI, it builds and runs fine. However, if I build it on the command-line using the plain old `javac` (i.e., without any `ant` or `maven` build tool), I get a `code too large` error on one of the files (which, btw, happens to be a Antlr3-generated Java parser file).

What's strange is:

1. My Eclipse project is pointing to the same JDK that I'm using on the command-line! So, it is not the case that I'm inadvertently using built-in Eclipse Java compiler
2. If the parser code were really 'too large' (some method in it being > 64K), why isn't the Eclipse build resulting in the same error? For this very reason, I'm also reluctant to start tweaking my parser grammar - a much more involved task.

I'm using Eclipse Neon and Oracle JDK 1.8.

Comment: The Eclipse UI always uses the Eclipse Java compiler, it never uses javac. So it may be the Eclipse compiler is doing a better job.

Comment: You mean, the Eclipse UI uses its own compiler **even if** I specify an external one in the Installed JREs? If yes, then what good is specifying our own compiler under Installed JREs?

Comment: The installed JRE is used for the libraries and the JVM when you are testing. Eclipse always uses its own compiler since it needs to do incremental compilation which javac can't do.

Comment: Aha! I got my answer now. Could you please paste your comments as an answer, so I can mark it as final?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Eclipse UI always uses the Eclipse Java compiler, it never uses javac. So it may be the Eclipse compiler is doing a better job in this case.

The installed JRE is used for the libraries and the JVM when you are testing. Eclipse always uses its own compiler since it needs to do incremental compilation which javac can't do.